# How can I add a class in ember js

Tags: ember.js

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="sideMenu">

        {{#link-to 'home'}}Home{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to 'posts'}}Posts{{/link-to}}
        </div>


        <div class="content">

        {{outlet}}
         </div>

        </div>

    </script>
```

I am new to ember js. How can I add a class on 'content' class each time when view changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do something like this:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  activate: function() {
    var cssClass = this.toCssClass();
    // you probably don't need the application class
    // to be added to the body
    if (cssClass !== 'application') {
      Ember.$('body').addClass(cssClass);
    }
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    Ember.$('body').removeClass(this.toCssClass());
  },
  toCssClass: function() {
    return this.routeName.replace(/\./g, '-').dasherize();
  }
});
```

It would add a class to the body (in your case just use content), that is the same as the current route.

Comment: Nicely done! It might make sense to cache the css class in a property instead of recomputing it in `deactivate` but that's probably a very minor addition to an elegant solution! Well done, @Asgaroth

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the `currentPath` property on the application controller to the class of the element in the template:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":content currentPath"}}>
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

In case you're not familiar with the `{{bind-attr class=` syntax in Ember/Handlebars:

- the class name preceded with a colon (`:content`) is always added to the element
- properties such as `currentPath` result in the current value of that property being inserted as a class, and are kept dynamically updated

To be able to access `currentPath` in a template being driven by a controller other than the application controller, first add

```
needs: ['application']
```

to the controller, which makes the application controller available under the name `controllers.application`, for use in the `bind-attr` as follows:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":content controllers.application.currentPath"}}>
```

You may use `currentRouteName` instead of or in addition to `currentPath` if that works better for you.

The class name added will be dotted, such as `uploads.index`. You can refer to that in your CSS by escaping the dot, as in

```
.uploads\.index { }
```

Or, if you would prefer dasherized, add a property to give the dasherized path, such as

```
dasherizedCurrentPath: function() {
    return this.('currentPath').replace(/\./g, '-');
}.property('currentPath')

<div {{bind-attr class=":content dasherizedCurrentPath"}}>
```

This has been tested in recent versions of ember-cli.

Comment: torazaburo, it would be great if you illustrated your idea with a jsbin example. I tried throwing something together and am not successful 100% (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tevupe/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output) `needs` is something used by controllers not routes, so I am not sure exactly how your answer would work in practice

Comment: My apologies. I should have said to place the `needs` in the *controller* corresponding to the template in question. Have updated my answer. Unfortunately, I don't have time to put together a jsbin at the moment.

Comment: I believe what the person was trying to do was to have a div in the application template with an outlet for children templates and that div in the application template would update itself with an appropriate class for whichever route is currently being displayed. Not sure if what you are suggesting would be able to solve that. I tried running with your solution (see comment above) but ran into a brick wall

Answer (score 0):

@torazaburo had some excellent points about @Asgaroth (accepted) answer, but I liked the idea of not having to write this same functionality over and over again. So, what I am providing below is a hybrid of the two solutions plus my own two cents and I believe it addresses @torazaburo concerns regarding the accepted answer.

Let's start with the 2nd point:

> I also don't like the idea of polluting Ember.Route

Can you pollute `Ember.Route` **without** polluting `Ember.Route`? (Huh?) Absolutely! :) Instead of overwriting `activate`, we can write our own function and tell it to run `.on(activate)` This way, our logic is run, but we are not messing with the built-in/inherited `activate` hook.

> The accepted answer is very procedural, imperative, jQuery-ish, and un-Ember-like.

I have to agree with this as well. In the accepted answer, we are abandoning Ember's data binding approach and instead fall back on the jQuery. Not only that, we then have to have more code in the `deactivate` to "clean up the mess".

So, here is my approach:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  setContentClass: function(){    
    this.controllerFor('application').set("path", this.routeName.dasherize());
  }.on('activate')
});
```

We add our own method to the `Ember.Route` class without **overwriting** `activate` hook. All the method is doing is setting a `path` property on the `application` controller.

Then, inside `application` template, we can bind to that property:

```
    <div {{bind-attr class=":content path"}}>
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tevupe/3/edit?html,js,console,output)